# c++ operator[uint] msvc x86 build fails, builds fine x64

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, language-lawyer, 64-bit, operator-keyword

Why no ambiguity for x64 and builds fine, and fails for x86?
In compiler explorer, any same 32/64 compilers give similar result:

```
<source>(24): error C2666: 'arrs<int,5>::operator []': 2 overloads have similar conversions
<source>(6): note: could be 'T &arrs<T,5>::operator [](uint32_t)'
        with
        [
            T=int
        ]
<source>(24): note: or       'built-in C++ operator[(T, int)'
        with
        [
            T=int
        ]
<source>(24): note: while trying to match the argument list '(arrs<int,5>, int)'
```

msvc x64/x86
https://godbolt.org/z/aavxj6

```
#include <cstdint>

template<class T, uint32_t N>
struct arrs
{
    T& operator[](uint32_t i)
    {
        return v[i];
    }

    operator T* ()
    {
        return v;
    }

    T v[N];

};


int main()
{
    arrs<int, 5> a;
    a[0] = 0;

    char x = 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting; GCC is basically the same https://godbolt.org/z/vsvG81: `-m32` warns that ISO C++ says `a[0]` is ambiguous because of allowed implicit conversions, but not in the default 64-bit build.  Its warning shows both candidates, including `operator[](int*, int) (built-in)`  (i.e. normal array indexing, probably after the `operator T*`).  But for GCC, it still compiles with `-m32`, and only warns instead of errors.  `warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second`

Comment: It seems likely that 64-bit builds having pointers of different size from `int` is the only thing that's different.  But why would that matter? I didn't think pointer->uintptr_t was a possible implicit conversion.  (In MSVC, `long` and `int` are the same size even for x64)